# How can I check if a user already exists before calling smooch.appUsers.get?

Tags: smooch

I'm developing a service using Smooch using the smooch-core NPM package.

Before I create a user, I want to check if that specific user id already exists in my app, and if not, I wish to create the new user.

Here is my code:

```
try {
      await this.smooch.appUsers.get(appId, userId);
    } catch (err) {
      await this.smooch.appUsers.create(appId, userId);
      await this.smooch.appUsers.get(appId, userId);
    }
```

I always get a 404 error when I try to get user info with non-existant id (smooch.appUsers.get), which I don't find to be a nice way.

Is there another way to check if user already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 `user_not_found` is the officially supported way to know when a user does not exist. Alternatively you could make your call to `appUsers.create` without doing the `appUsers.get` first, and you will receive 409 `conflict` in the case where the user already exists.

Note also that the call to `.create` returns the created user, so you shouldn't need to do a second `.get` after that (referring to the snippet you posted)